# Is it possible to label a DNA molecule using a radioactive sulphur?

Tags: molecular-biology

The radioactive labelling of the DNA molecule is possible using radioactive phosphorus and tritium atom. But is it any how possible to label the DNA  molecule using a radioactive sulphur atom?

Comment: @AliceD I honestly don't understand the argument that his question isn't about biology. I can't really think of any reason to label DNA this way that wouldn't be part of a biological experiment. (of course adding the motivation would improve the question, but it is not necessary to make it on-topic in this case).

Comment: @MadScientist point taken. I'll remove the comment. However, adding background helps to add the 'prior research component' too. It would just greatly enhance question quality.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible, and indeed this was the standard labelling procedure used in early Sanger sequencing.

You synthesise DNA using a deoxynucleotide with a sulphur replacing an oxygen on the α phosphate as shown below. This phosphate forms the phosphodiester link in nucleic acids so the sulphur is incorporated.

The image is of dATPαS
 [image: alphaS]

---

**response to David's comments**

Please note that:

1. DNA does not normally contain sulphur.
2. This technique is for *in vitro* labelling of DNA; as far as I am aware it isn't possible to label with sulphur *in vivo.*

Comment: I have down-voted your answer as the radio-active molecule produced by the method you suggest is not chemically DNA but an analogue thereof.

Comment: Please go to chat for extended discussions. Because of raised flags and the general negative tone,  I've removed most of the comments here. Please keep it civil.

Comment: http://www.nature.com/nchembio/journal/v3/n11/full/nchembio.2007.39.html